# .match() returns null for regular expression of password

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written javascript code to check **Minimum 4 and Maximum 8 characters at least 1 Uppercase Alphabet, 1 Lowercase Alphabet, 1 Number and 1 Special Character**, but it returns null for both wrong and right string. I don't know whats issue. pls help.

```
var password = 'okK1@'; // you can take anything
var a;
a = password.match("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@@$!%*?&]{4,8}");
if(a == false){
  alert('false');
}
else if (a == true){
  alert('true');
}
else{
  alert('null');
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't easier to build individual checks for each "rule", while also returning a specific error message to the user, saying exactly _what_ is wrong, shouldn't the PW validate?

Comment: Wrap the string inside `new RegExp(... string here ...)` or use `/regex here/` notation.

Comment: Don't you have to use `\\d` inside of a String in JavaScript? I think the single escape only works if you use `/.../` stype regexp.

Comment: Why maximum eight characters for password?

Comment: @Jack client requirement.

Comment: How could that ever be a requirement? Unless they're storing passwords in the clear, which they also shouldn't be doing.

Comment: Tell the client it's a stupid requirement that makes passwords ___easier___ to crack / bruteforce. It's making the passwords ___less___ safe. That should convince them to let users use longer PW's.

Comment: @Jack i know bt pls help tp solve issue. I have tried `/regex/` but still return null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't support look-behind in regular expressions; that said, it's easier to split up the requirements:

```
var password = ...;

var errors = [];

if (password.length < 4 /* || password.length > 8 */) {
    errors.push("Password must be at least 4 characters");
}
if (!/[A-Z]/.test(password)) {
    errors.push("Password must contain at least one uppercase letter");
}
if (!/[a-z]/.test(password)) {
    errors.push("Password must contain at least one lowercase letter");
}
if (!/\d/.test(password)) {
    errors.push("Password must contain at least one digit");
}
if (!/[$@!%*?&]/.test(password)) {
    errors.push("Password must contain at least one special character");
}
```

You can choose to exit early using a `return false;`, but doing it in this manner will have the advantage of telling the user exactly why their password is not good.

Comment: very diff from usually i do

Comment: Is it possible to add all special symbol: `,!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,-,.,_

Comment: @Dhwani Sure, just add any missing characters in the set, but make sure the hyphen is either the first or last character.

Comment: @Jack well,if i upvote your answer then definitely it's good ;) (and i have)